# Selenium WebDriverError on Rails 3.2 with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I have a Rails 3.2 app. I am trying to set up cucumber tests to run using Google chrome. I have added config for the same:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Also, I have installed the chromedriver with its binary in /usr/bin/  :

```
➜  ~  ls -lah /usr/bin | grep chrome
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root     18M May 20 15:42 chromedriver
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      32 Apr  6 10:19 google-chrome -> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

When I try to run a simple feature which just opens google.com and searches something, I get the following error:

```
unexpected response, code=404, content-type=""
      unknown command: session/url (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
      ./features/step_definitions/google_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on the google page$/'
      features/google.feature:3:in `Given I am on the google page'
```

Rest of the trace:

```
unexpected response, code=404, content-type=""
      unknown command: session/url (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:619:in `raw_execute'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:597:in `execute'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:103:in `get'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:90:in `reset!'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:77:in `reset!'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `block in reset_sessions!'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `each'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `reset_sessions!'
      /home/arkiver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@tests/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:10:in `After'
```

Need help figuring out what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. I was (accidently?) using the wrong driver version:

From https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list , I downloaded this version:

" chromedriver_linux64_26.0.1383.0.zip  ChromeDriver server for linux64 "

Instead of my previously selected:

"  chromedriver2_linux64_0.8.zip     version of ChromeDriver2 r195627   Release "

That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  In my case I had the latest driver, but I needed to update the selenium gem I was using to the latest version as well.